# Wordpress navwalker nested menu

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying create a nested menu in WordPress using the WP Navwalker. I have found a lot of informations but i can not apply the tips successfully. I believe that the problem is regarding the classes used in site since it was created by other person.

What i'd like to do is

1. Menu

   - Item 1

     - Item 1.1 (displayed when hover the Item 1)

The link 'Serviços de Simulação' should be a submenu and it is displayed below of the same menu.

[Submenu below of the main item wrongly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbamP.png)

Header.php

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl fixed-top navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']; ?>" alt="Mechworks">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-collapse" aria-controls="menu-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse float-right" id="menu-collapse">
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
          /*'menu'              => 'primary',*/
          'theme_location'    => 'primary',
          'depth'             => 3,
          'container'         => 'true',
          'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
          'container_id'      => 'menu-collapse',
          'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav ml-auto text-center',
          'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
          'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker())
        );?>
        <div class="box-search"></div>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>`
```

Functions.php

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'Mechworks' ),
    'footer1' => __( 'Footer 1' ),
    'footer2' => __( 'Footer 2' ),
    'footer3' => __( 'Footer 3' ),
) );

// Register Custom Navigation Walker
require_once get_template_directory() . '/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
```

Also, i have changed the wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php for it

`*$item_output .= ( $args->has_children && 0 === $depth ) ? ' <span class="caret"></span></a>' : '</a>';`